# Column to list using delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, list, split, delimiter

Need to split the column into multiple columns. Works on excel using a space delimiter.

```
            2.11           OBSERVATION DATA    GPS(GPS)            RINEX VERSION / TYPE
0       cnvtToRINEX 2.30.0  convertToRINEX OPR  08-Mar...                              
1       ----------------------------------------------...                              
2       OFFICE                                        ...                              
3                                                     ...                              
4       GNSS Observer       Trimble                   ...                              
5       0220329451          5700                2.26  ...                              
6                           TRM39105.00               ...                              
7         5018389.6272  1676641.6590 -3549783.0761    ...                              
8               0.0000        0.0000        0.0000    ...                              
9            1     1     0                            ...                              
10           4    C1    L1    L2    P2                ...                              
11        1997     7    23     6    28   40.0000000   ...                              
12        1997     7    23     7    45   13.0000000   ...                              
13           0                                        ...                              
14          12                                        ...                              
15          10                                        ...                              
16         G01 45525 45512 45521 45521                ...
```

Comment: Are they separated by tab or just multiple spaces?

Comment: Just multiple spaces, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like an excel, but you can try split using regex by defining multiple spaces:

```
import re

for x in lines:
    s = re.split(r'\s\s+', x) # split on more than 2 spaces
    # process the line
```

But by observation your data has some corner cases, and there's no clear delimiter so I cannot guarantee it works perfectly (and I don't think there can be any).

For example:

> 1676641.6590 -3549783.0761

Seems to be separated by only one space, and you can't tell it from a word, you don't want to split below right?

> GNSS Observer

Comment: Hi shot for the answer, can just split everything as well don't really mind. End goal is to replace the current date values with the correct date.

Comment: You can't see the date on the example above, but its in the same wacko list format

Comment: @M.Lord Which row is the date? If it follows certain pattern, you can find it using regex then.

Comment: got it working using df.replace usage of pandas - the data was all reading in as one column